# Having componentResized only perform action after jJFrame is no longer being resized

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to find a way that will have the JFrame's component listener perform actions only after the user is done resizing it. I tried doing it by using a mouse listener and as long as the user is clicking, it wont perform any action, but will when they release it. Sadly, the resizing does not trigger the mouse listener. Any suggestions?

Comment: *"have the JFrame's component listener perform actions only after the user is done resizing it"* Why? See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Right now I'm trying to have it re-scale components at the end based of the change in ratio between the new and old JFrame size, but since it triggers the component resized several times, it doesn't properly resize it.

Comment: Start a Swing `Timer` with small delay, keep restarting when ever `componentResized` is called - this stop the timer from triggering until the resize events stop, once it does trigger you can assume that there is enough of delay between now and the last event to do some work

Comment: Ok thank you I will try that

Comment: @MadProgrammer gave a good strategy to try, but note that Java layout managers are very good at resizing components properly to suit the size of a top level container like a frame.

Comment: @AndrewThompson There I thought they were re-scaling images :P